# How to get some string of dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have dataframe like this.

```
print(df)

[    ID   ...   Control
0  PDF-1  ...     NaN
1  PDF-3  ...     NaN
2  PDF-4  ...     NaN
```

I want to get only number of ID column. So the result will be.

```
1
3
4
```

How to get one of the strings of the dataframe column ?

Comment: `df.ID.str.rsplit('-', n=1).str[-1]`

Comment: `df['ID'].str.extract(r'(PDF-)(\d+)').iloc[:,-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just replace a common `PDF-` prefix?

```
df['ID'].str.replace('PDF-', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
df['ID'].replace(regex=True,to_replace=r'([^\d])',value=r'')
```

One could refer documentation for [df.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Basically using regex to remove everything apart from digits in column named `ID` where `\d` denotes digits and when we use `[^\d]` means apart form digits match everything.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility using *Regex* is:

```
df.ID.str.extract('(\d+)')
```

This avoids changing the original data just to extract the integers.

So for the following simple example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['PDF-1','PDF-2','PDF-3','PDF-4','PDF-5']})
print(df.ID.str.extract('(\d+)'))
print(df)
```

we get the following:

```
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5

   ID
0  PDF-1
1  PDF-2
2  PDF-3
3  PDF-4
4  PDF-5
```

Answer (score 0):

Find "PDF-" ,and replace it with nothing
`df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.replace('PDF-', '')`
Then to print how you asked I'd convert the data frame to a string with no index.
`print df['cleanID'].to_string(index=False)`